# Show that every prime number greater than $3$ is of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that every prime number greater than $3$ is of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

Looking at couple of cases it seems that $6(0)+1=5$ and $6(1)+1=7$ starting from $5$ every other prime can be expressed as $6k+1$. My inital guess was if I could use induction to show this, but didn't quite get it to work. I also considered if I could get a contradiction, but couldn't formalize that also. Is this possible with either option?

Answer (score 1):

This immediately follows from the fact that a prime $p\ge 5$ is coprime to $6$

Answer (score 0):

$6k, 6k+2=2(3k+1), 6k+3=3(2k+1)$ and $6k+4=2(3k+2)$ are obviously composite.

Comment: I see. Can we conclude directly from this the problem statement?

Comment: @Nate: what do you mean ?

Comment: ... for $k\ge 1$

Comment: @Henry: … or $n=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a slightly different proof, let's start with something more general:

Let $n$ be any number not divisible by $2$ or $3$, and write $n=6k+r$ with $0\le r\lt6$. Since $2\not\mid n$, we cannot have $r=0$, $2$, or $4$, and since $3\not\mid n$, we cannot have $r=3$.  This leaves only $r=1$ and $r=5$. So if a number $n$ is not divisible by $2$ or $3$, then $n$ is of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$.

Now if $p$ is a *prime* greater than $3$, then $p$ is, by definition, not divisible by $2$ or $3$. Hence $p$ is of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$.