# Attempting to prove the claim: "Every prime greater than $3$ can be written in the form $6n + 1$ or $6n + 5$" by induction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction

Claim:

> Every prime greater than $3$ can be written in the form $6n + 1$ or $6n + 5$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z^+$.

Proof (my attempt):

Base case: $n=0$.

> $6n + 5 = 6*0 + 5 = 5$, which is prime.

Inductive hypothesis: Suppose the statement $S(n)$ is true for some $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Inductive step: $S(n + 1)$

> $6(n + 1) + 1 = p > 3$ or $6(n + 1) + 5 = p > 3$

By induction, the claim is true.

This is my attempt, but it seems fishy.

**Is this proof sound?**

Comment: You mention "S(n)" but **never** state clearly what that is.

Comment: It is the statement that "Every prime greater than 3 can be written in the form 6n + 1 or 6n + 5 is for all n in {0,1,2,...}"

Comment: Fix $n$. Consider the elements $6n$, $6n+1$, $6n+2$, $6n+3$, $6n+4$, $6n+5$. Some of them are clearly not prime. So there is no need for an induction. (Except we use it and never use the induction assumption.)

Comment: Induction is a strange way to prove this claim.  What index would you do induction on?

Comment: So $S(2)$ would be "Every prime greater than $3$ can be written in the form $13$ or $17$ is for all $2$ in $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$". That makes no sense.

Comment: Compare your proof with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732524/show-that-every-prime-number-greater-than-3-is-of-the-form-6k1-or-6k5-w?rq=1).

Comment: Claims of the form "there exists an $n$" can't be proved by induction for $n$. An inductive step of "there exists an $n+1$ makes no sense.

Comment: Formal statement: $\quad$

$\quad S : (\forall p \in \Bbb N) \,\big[\,p \text{ prime} \implies [(\exists n \in \Bbb N) [p = 6n + 1 \lor p = 6n + 5] \, \big]$

$\quad$ now prove statement $S$ with induction on $p$. But you don't need much of the inductive hypothesis to get to the next step (strong induction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we don’t use induction to prove this. Honestly I want to know a sound induction proof if there exists one.

You can clearly see

1. $2|6n+2$
2. $2|6n+4$
3. $2|6n$
4. $3|6n+3$

So except for $2$ and $3$, all the primes can be written as $6n+1$ or $6n+5$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ As for many induction problems often the key is to *strengthen* the induction hypothesis to a form that eases the inductive step. Note that the primes $> 3$ are coprime to $\,2,3\,$ so coprime to $\,6$.

Thus it suffices to prove that naturals coprime to $\,6\,$ have form $\,1+6k\,$ or $\,5+6k,\,$ and this has an obvious (complete) induction step because  $\,\gcd(n+6,6) = \gcd(n,6)\,$ by Euclid, therefore we infer that $\,n+6\,$ is coprime to $\,6\iff n$ is coprime to $6,\,$ so a (complete) induction reduces the truth of the statement to that of the obviously true base case of naturals $\,< 6$.

Comment: Shouldn't your induction hypothesis be something like $\gcd(k+6n,6)=\gcd(k,6)$? What is your induction variable that you increase for the induction step (it's not $n$)?

Comment: @Wolfgang There was a name clash with the OP's notation (now renamed).

Answer (score 0):

Since $p$ must be coprime to $6$ and $\phi(6)=2$, "Euler's Theorem" gives us
$$p^2\equiv1\pmod6$$
Therefore, $6\mid p^2-1$ and so also $6\mid p^2-1-6p+6=(p-1)(p-5)$. From $3\mid6$, we also have $3\mid (p-1)(p-5)$, and (since $p$ is a prime) it follows that $3\mid p-1$ or $3\mid p-5$. Since $2$ devides both factors (and $2$ and $3$ are coprime), we conclude that $2\cdot3=6\mid p-1$ or $6\mid p-5$. This means that there exists some integer $n$ such that $6n=p-1$ or $6n=p-5$, in other words $p=6n+1$ or $p=6n+5$.